# Automated importing/sizing of image illustrator

Tags: applescript, adobe-illustrator

I’m trying to find a way to place an image into an illustrator document with AppleScript, but I can’t find a place image command that works.

Ideally I would give the AppleScript my image’s file path, and it would place said image in a file when executed.

Anybody do this before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have the [Adobe Illustrator CC 2017 Reference PDF](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/illustrator/scripting.html)? This example is straight out of it:

```
-- This function adds a new placed item to a document from a file reference,
-- fileToPlace, which is passed in during the function call, fileToPlace is an
-- alias or file reference to an art file, which must be set up before calling this
-- function, itemPosition is a fixed point at which to position the placed item

on PlacedItemCreate(fileToPlace)
  tell application "Adobe Illustrator"
    set itemPosition to {100.0, 200.0}
    set placedRef to make new placed item in document 1 ¬
    with properties {file path:fileToPlace, position:itemPosition}
  end tell
end PlacedItemCreate
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Thank you.